# Panels taking unnecessarily huge space in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs, panel

​I ​have a panel in a ​Ext​Js `Viewport` with `BorderLayout` .
It is really taking a huge space on the screen. If I change the layout to
​c​ard from ​fit ​it does not make a difference. ​I have to scroll down to see the buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/fastcodejava/VvKck/7/embedded/result/

Comment: They are spanning whole width of container, it is ok (by design).

Comment: @kirilloid Can you explain that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check my update to your [code](http://jsfiddle.net/VvKck/8/) where was some wrongly used minWindth, removed layout fit on top and missing some parts and needed to add MaxWidth to bottom part. You can check the full code on the fiddle link

```
layout: 'border',
    maxWidth : 400,
```

Comment: ​Good answer, but when I apply the card layout in the center region the panel becomes huge taking up the whole space. How do I just show the form with card layout in the center? http://jsfiddle.net/fastcodejava/H7LjW/1/

Comment: maybe this update will work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/H7LjW/2/ Or the problem is with the colapsible panel?

Comment: I guess this can be solved with a `maxHeight` option. This is kind of artificial, we have to be manually tweak this for all the forms.